# Profile Visibility Settings fields

Tags: user

[image]Where exactly below setting fields stored in salesforce. I could not find below fields in User Object. I need to access below fields via apex.

[image: Profile Visibility Page]

These fields are available for us to edit from Lightning napili template community under My settings, we could not find what are the field names for above fields in user object.

Answer (score 0):

The image you cite is not familiar to me so my answer may be wrong here but
generally-speaking you can find both field labels and their API name by opening the Users > Field page within the Salesforce Setup Menu.  Alternatively you could use a tool like Workbench for Salesforce as it has a nice query builder built-in.  Here are some queryable datafields on the standard User sObject that look relevant to your needs:

**Photo fields:**
BannerPhotoUrl
FullPhotoUrl
IsProfilePhotoActive
MediumBannerPhotoUrl
MediumPhotoUrl
SmallBannerPhotoUrl
SmallPhotoUrl
UserPreferencesHideBiggerPhotoCallout

**Other fields**
Title,Phone,MobilePhone,Address,ManagerId,Email